# What is the best way to implement standard button in custom lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, custom-button, standard-objects, custom

[image]

hello, i would like to use default salesforce "new opporunity" button that opens modal and is able to save new opportunity. like in the photo, is it even possible? because i can't find straightforward solution, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "New" button on a related list is a standard quick action (*unless you've overridden it with a custom component or page*), so calling that quick action from the LWC would be the best way to implement this and keep the two buttons consistent.

The Quick Action API isn't available in LWCs (yet) but you can use an [Aura component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:quickActionAPI/documentation) in conjunction with your LWC using `lightning:quickActionAPI`.

You can also use the Navigation mixin to navigate the user to the "new record" page:

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__objectPage',
    attributes: {
        objectApiName: 'Opportunity',
        actionName: 'new'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way out, apart form @nbrown 's great answer: The best practice here might be to take the advantage of LWC "Base components". These components are read-to-use functions, that mimics standard salesforce functionalities.

**Steps:**

1. Attach an onclick handler to a lightning-button and place the button where needed.
2. On Click, launch a lightning modal, that will contain a 'Create Record' Form
3. Inside the modal,implement the form using *Lightning-record-form*.

   ```
             <lightning-record-form
                object-api-name="{objectApiName}" //opportunity 
               record-id="{recordId}"
               fields="{fields}"
             </lightning-record-form>
   ```

This component(lightning-record-form) acts as a ready-made implementation of the STANDARD salesforce create and edit functionality. In case of edit, you need to populate the {recordId}. If user is **creating** a new record, you can omit the recordId.

Thanks!
Note: This solution enforces seperation of LWC from Aura/VF as its motivation.

Resource:

Offical Salesforce resource:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_create_record

Blog guide: https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/lightning-record-form-lwc/

Comment: @nbrown's suggestion with using Navigation is the best one, as you will provide like for like experience, and if the standard page layout etc. is used then the 'new' popup is presented over YOUR component.

Comment: Agreed. But wih the overhead, of again involving the LWC within an aura container and then invoking aura-compatible API's to make this happen.
Typically, I would consider mixing Aura,LWC and VF together  to be not a good option, as in coming years, aura might phase out. But, yep, we can choose as needed.

Comment: Nah i meant `NavigationMixin.Navigate` one, that doesn't involve aura at all

Answer (score -2):

Here is the step to create a custom button. Switch to lightning experience.

1. Go to Setup > Objects and Fields > Object Manager.
2. Select an object in which you want to add lightning action.
3. Go to Buttons, Links, and Actions related lists.
4. Click on New Action.
5. You will observe a picklist with the label Action Type.
6. Select the Lightning Component option.